# how to stop the animation at the last frame?

Tags: iphone, animation

How I can stop animation on the last frame. 
Code here:

`- (void)method{`

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSInteger i;
for (i = 0; i < 75; i++){ 

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pictures%i.png", i];
    UIImage *img =[UIImage imageNamed:str];
    [images addObject:img];

}
// Begin the animation
somePicture = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"8Ball_003_00075.png"]];
//somePicture = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)] autorelease];
//[somePicture isAnimating]==0;
somePicture.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[somePicture setAnimationImages:images];
somePicture.animationDuration = 5.0f;
somePicture.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[somePicture startAnimating];
somePicture.center = CGPointMake(160.0f, 230.0f);

//[images release];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.5f target: self selector: @selector(tick) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

[self.view addSubview:somePicture];

}

-(void)tick{

```
if(![somePicture isAnimating]) { [timer invalidate]; [somePicture stopAnimating]; timer=nil; NSLog(@"@ye1111eah!!!");}
else
NSLog(@"@y");}
```

I know that I must used NSTimer but i don't know how :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you allocate `somePicture` twice

```
somePicture = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"8Ball_003_00075.png"]];
somePicture = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)] autorelease];
```

Can't you just use this

```
somePicture = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"8Ball_003_00075.png"]];
somePicture.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f);
```

**UPDATE**

I think this will do it

```
    - (void)method{

    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSInteger i;
    for (i = 0; i < 75; i++){ 

        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pictures%i.png", i];
        UIImage *img =[UIImage imageNamed:str];
        [images addObject:img];

    }
    // Begin the animation
    somePicture = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"8Ball_003_00075.png"]];
    somePicture.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f);
    self.view addSubview:somePicture];
    //[somePicture isAnimating]==0;
    [somePicture setAnimationImages:images];
    somePicture.animationDuration = 5.0f;
    somePicture.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    somePicture.center = CGPointMake(160.0f, 230.0f);
    [somePicture startAnimating];
 [self performSelector:@selector(tick) withObject:self afterDelay:5.0];

    }
- (void)tick
{
[somePicture stopAnimating];
if(![somePicture isAnimating]) 
{ 
    NSLog(@"@ye1111eah!!!");
}
else
NSLog(@"@y");
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Yes, animating stop on the last frame, but I used timer fo new method tick, this method must put in console @ye1111eah!!! but timer don't stop :(

Comment: For this I used timer that I invalidate in method tick

Comment: I am sorry you dont need to use the timer. Why do you want to use the timer.

Comment: you need to use stopAnimating for the method isAnimating to return NO.

Comment: How do I know when the animation has stopped?

Comment: Use my answer you will get what you want.